# Can habeo introduce a relative clause of purpose?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, syntax

In Cicero's letter to Atticus from November 68 BC, he writes this:
*Porrō autem neque mihi accidit ut habērem quī in Ēpīrum proficīscerētur nequedum tē Athēnīs esse audiēbāmus.*  
 
This is how I translated it:
"And furthermore it didn't happen to me that I have to set out for Epirus, and we didn't hear yet that you were in Athens."  
 
Would haberem here be indeed introducing a relative clause of purpose or did I miss something here with this verb?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an implied *aliquem*, which is the antecedent of the purpose *qui* clause. In my translations, I use an infinitive rather than a relative clause to represent purpose, which is appropriate for English idiom.

Here's a good parallel passage, from *Ep. 14.16*:

Etsi eius modi tempora nostra sunt ut **nihil habeam quod aut** a te litterarum **exspectem aut** ipse ad te **scribam**, tamen nescio quo modo et ipse vestras litteras exspecto et scribo ad vos cum **habeo qui ferat**.

Even though our times are such that I have no letter either to expect from you or to write to you, nevertheless somehow I both expect your letters and write [my own] to you, whenever I have [someone] to deliver [them].

Following the same logic, your passage reads:

I didn't happen to have anyone to set out for Epirus...

or

It so happened that I didn't have anyone who would set out for Epirus...